# How to Optimally Save Data in Python as Data Structure

Tags: python, dictionary

My model returns information about PC games in the following format. The format is `game index` and `game value`. This is my `sim_sorted`.

```
[(778, 0.99999994), (1238, 0.9999997), (1409, 0.99999905), (1212, 0.99999815)]
```

I retrieve the information about the game by indexing the database (df_indieGames):

```
sims_sorted = sorted(enumerate(sims), key=lambda item: -item[1])

results = {}
    for val in sims_sorted[:4]:
        index, value = val[0], val[1]
        results[df_indieGames.game_name.loc[index]] = 
   {
        "Genre":df_indieGames.genre.loc[index],
        "Rating": df_indieGames.score.loc[index],
        "Link": df_indieGames.game_link[index]
    }
```

However, such a data structure is hard to sort (by Rating). Is there a better way to store the information so retrieval and sorting is easier? Thanks.

Here's the output of results:

```
{u'Diehard Dungeon': {'Genre': u'Roguelike',
  'Link': u'http://www.indiedb.com/games/diehard-dungeon',
  'Rating': 8.4000000000000004},
 u'Fork Truck Challenge': {'Genre': u'Realistic Sim',
  'Link': u'http://www.indiedb.com/games/fork-truck-challenge',
  'Rating': 7.4000000000000004},
 u'Miniconomy': {'Genre': u'Realistic Sim',
  'Link': u'http://www.indiedb.com/games/miniconomy',
  'Rating': 7.2999999999999998},
 u'World of Padman': {'Genre': u'First Person Shooter',
  'Link': u'http://www.indiedb.com/games/world-of-padman',
  'Rating': 9.0}}
```

**UPDATE**

The solution to the problem as suggested by ziddarth is the following:

```
result = sorted(results.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1]['Rating'], reverse=True)
```

Comment: check out http://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: To sort by rating you could use the lambda technique again `sorted(results.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1]['Rating'])`

Comment: @ziddarth: That does solve the problem. Could you write it as a solution so I can mark it as done and you can have the points. Thanks!

Comment: Also, is there a more efficient way to save this information as a data structure? Or is this a good way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by rating using code below. The lambda function is called with a tuple whose first element is the dictionary key and the second element is the dictionary value for the corresponding key, so you can use the lambda function to get to any value in the nested dictionary

```
sorted(results.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1]['Rating'])
```